# How can I disable mouse wheel scrolling of Firefox tabs?

Tags: firefox, mouse-wheel

I'm on a laptop, and my touchpad is multitouch. I'm using Firefox 22.0

By tapping with 2 fingers it can simulate a mouse middle-click.
By scrolling with 2 fingers it will simulate a wheel mouse.
Sometimes it gets these two mixed up and will do both.

To close a Firefox tab, I almost always use middle-click (2 finger tap) on the tab. Though, about 1/4 of the time it quickly scrolls through my tabs and closes the wrong tab. (Who the hell uses mouse wheel on their tabs anyway?)

I don't want to resize my tabs, I have over 100 tabs open at any given time. If possible, I want to disable Firefox from scrolling tabs with the mouse wheel.

Comment: You have not indicated what version of FF you are running, so you are unlikely to get a response.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see this behavior (scroll wheel scrolls between tabs) on any of my stock Firefox installs.

Perhaps this is added by an extension such as Tab Mix Plus?

If so, you can go to

- Tab Mix Plus options
- Mouse
- Mouse Gestures tab
- Uncheck "allow scrolling to select tab"

(source: http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=1736255 )

Comment: I do not have Tabs Mix Plus installed. When you have more tabs than what can fit on the screen, the view of tabs becomes scrollable via mouse wheel. It is not "scroll to select".

Comment: I don't have this behaviour either. But on Chrome I do and I hate it: http://superuser.com/questions/709078/chrome-how-to-disable-scroll-over-tabs

Answer (score 0):

For me it was from All in One Gestures.  Uncheck: "Scroll Wheel in Tab Bar" and "Scroll Wheel Navigation".

Answer (score 0):

This is apparently now built in to firefox

- Go to `about:config`
- Set `toolkit.tabbox.switchByScrolling` to either `false` to disable this, or `true` to enable it.  It should be disabled by default.